# Explain the bash command "exec > >(tee $LOG_FILE) 2>&1"

Tags: bash, exec, io-redirection

My intent was to have all the output of my bash script displayed on the console and logged to a file.

Here is my script that works as expected.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE="test_log.log"
touch $LOG_FILE

# output to console and to logfile
exec > >(tee $LOG_FILE) 2>&1

echo "Starting command ls"
ls -al
echo "End of script"
```

However I do not understand why it works that way.

I expected to have `exec >>(tee $LOG_FILE) 2>&1` work but it fails although `exec >>$LOG_FILE 2>&1` indeed works.

I could not find the reason for the construction `exec > >(command )` in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) nor in [advanced bash scripting](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). Can you explain the logic behind it ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `>(tee $LOG_FILE)` is an example of *Process substitution*, you might wish to search for that.  [Advanced Shell Scriptng](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) and [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)

Using the syntax, `<(program)` for capturing output and `>(program)` for feeding input, we can pass data just one record at a time.  It is more powerful than command substitution (backticks, or `$( )`) because it substitutes for a *filename*, not text.  Therefore anywhere a file is normally specified we can substitute a program's standard output or input (although process substitution on input is not all that common).
This is particularly useful where a program does not use standard streams for what you want.

Note that in your example you are missing a space, `exec >>(tee $LOG_FILE) 2>&1` is *wrong* (you will get a syntax error). Rather,

```
exec > >(tee $LOG_FILE) 2>&1
```

is correct, that space is critical.

So, the `exec >` part changes file descriptor 1 (the default), also known as `stdout` or *standard output*, to refer to "whatever comes next", in this case it is the process substitution, although normally it would be a filename.

`2>&1` redirects file descriptor 2 (`stderr` or *standard error*) to refer to the same place as file descriptor 1 (`stdout` or *standard out*). *Important:* if you omit the `&` you end-up with a file called `1` rather than successful redirection.

Once you have called the `exec` line above, then you have changed the current process's standard output, so output from the commands which follow go to that `tee` process instead of to regular `stdout`.

Comment: I have seen that command on multiple posts, but it just won't work for me no matter what I try. I don't know what I'm missing. I keep getting error:
``` syntax error near unexpected token `>' ``` Anyone has any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Ah, I found where I went wrong. I was calling the script (that contains the command) with "sh <path-to-script>". It works when i use "bash <path-to-script>". The script is prepended with "#/bin/bash", I thought that would run the script using Bash, but I guess I still have some learning to do about shell scripting in unix :).

Comment: @Kenny The `#!` prefix (I assume the missing `!` was a typo) is read as a comment if you specify the shell on the command-line.  `sh` is not the same as `bash`.  On some platforms `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash` but `bash` is clever and attempts to behave as `sh` if it is run that way (a program can find out which name has been used to call it).

Comment: @cdarke that was indeed a typo :) thanks for the clarification, really helpful!

Comment: Using `exec > >(tee $LOG_FILE) 2>&1` is _incredibly useful for logging all output from an executable script called as a cron job!_ See this Q&A as well: [Super User: How can I view results of my cron jobs?](https://superuser.com/q/122246/425838), especially [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/569315/425838).