# Log bash output (stderr, and stdout) to multiple files one at a time in one script

Tags: bash, exec, file-descriptor

Suppose you have a bash script and you want to print and also save the output (stderr, and stdout) to a log file. Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49514467/835098 by @cdarke, this is how you can do it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

exec > >(tee my.log) 2>&1

echo "Hello"
```

But what if you have a script where different sections need to go to different log files? Let's say you want to separate the typical `configure`, `make`, `make test` output each into their individual log file? A naive approach could look like this (for the sake of simplicity `configure` and alike became `echo`s here):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# clear logs
rm -f configure.log make.log make_test.log

exec > >(tee configure.log) 2>&1
echo "configure"

exec > >(tee make.log) 2>&1
echo "make"

exec > >(tee make_test.log) 2>&1
echo "make test"
```

But when you execute this script, you'll notice that only the last output contains what it's supposed to contain:

```
$ tail *.log
==> configure.log <==
configure
make
make test

==> make.log <==
make
make test

==> make_test.log <==
make test
```

Also notice that each log file begins with the correct output. I thought about sticking with one log file and truncating it after copying an intermediate piece of it to the final destination. This script works but I wonder if it is any good:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# clear logs
rm -f configure.log make.log make_test.log tmp.log

exec > >(tee tmp.log) 2>&1
echo "configure"
cp tmp.log configure.log && truncate -s 0 tmp.log

echo "make"
cp tmp.log make.log && truncate -s 0 tmp.log

echo "make test"
cp tmp.log make_test.log  && truncate -s 0 tmp.log
```

Here are the resulting log files:

```
$ tail *.log
==> configure.log <==
configure

==> make.log <==
make

==> make_test.log <==
make test

==> tmp.log <==
```

For example one downside of this approach is that a final log file will be available if the command succeeded. Actually, this is pretty bad and a good reason to find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because, you are duplicating stdout file descriptor in each call to `exec`, causing your output from all the three `echo` calls to all the three files. i.e. after setting the initial `exec`, when you did

```
exec > >(tee make.log) 2>&1
echo "make"
```

Not only the recent echo'd statement goes to `make.log`, but also to `configure.log`, because your previous `exec` did set up write to that log file for contents from stdout. Now the first log file contains lines from both the echo'd statements. This is replicated again in your next case also.

To avoid this problem, set-up different file descriptors for each unique case, i.e.

```
exec 3> >(tee configure.log) 2>&1
echo "configure" >&3

exec 4> >(tee make.log) 2>&1
echo "make" >&4

exec 5> >(tee make_test.log) 2>&1
echo "make test" >&5

# Releasing the file descriptors back to shell
exec 3>&-
exec 4>&-
exec 5>&-
```

Or if you are using a bash version >4.1, you can let the shell assign you the file descriptors, so that you don't have to pick the numbers explicitly.

```
exec {fd1}> >(tee configure.log) 2>&1
echo "configure" >&"$fd1"

exec {fd2}> >(tee make.log) 2>&1
echo "make" >&"$fd2"

exec {fd3}> >(tee make_test.log) 2>&1
echo "make test" >&"$fd3"
```

When you do `exec {fd1}>`, bash automatically, populates `fd1` variable with a file descriptor (usually greater than 10). Now you can use `$fd1` like before in your call along with `tee`. As before, you can free up the used descriptors by closing them as

```
exec >&"$fd1"-
exec >&"$fd2"-
exec >&"$fd3"-
```

---

If you want the stderr also to go to the corresponding log files, change your re-direction `2>&1` to the corresponding file descriptors opened, i.e.

```
2>&3        
2>&"$fd1"
```